# Programmatically access Excel's edit history

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint

For a project of mine, I have an Excel file stored in Sharepoint. Multiple users have access to the file and are able to make changes to the tables. Each week, a Python script is run to push the data into a data warehouse. I want to keep track of who made what changes in the data.

My main question is: **is it is possible to programmatically access the edit history of an Excel file?**

If yes:

- is it possible to access a specific cell's edit history?
- does the edit history include which user made the change?

Comment: Edit history isn't saved in the cell itself. It's saved in the application used to edit the file. Very few file formats "supports" edit history. Hence why `git` and version control is a thing I guess. Try this: Open your application of choice to edit, do a bunch of changes, save the file, close the application and re-open it and try to undo the changes.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess that answers my question. Thanks. By the way, if you happen to be the person that voted to close the question, can you explain why? I would like to understand why my question would not be considered suitable

Comment: It was, because this (when you know the answer) is more a question about general software and how it works *(operating/file-systems and file formats)*. It's a gray area since you're trying to solve it programatically - but since it's not possible due to general software restrictions I voted to close it under the topic "General hardware of software questions". It had nothing to do with the formatting of your question so don't worry about the vote(s) to much, won't affect your scores - just helps clear which search results are relevant for others ending up here :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies. I am not too worried about my score but wanted to better understand so I don't post more questions which others think should be closed :) and yeah fair enough, it's a grey area

Comment: As @Torxed has pointed out, this specific question is considered off-topic. However, you did say that the file is stored in SharePoint, which should keep a version-history of the file. You should be able to poll that information from the REST API of SharePoint [as this post answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/179450). The specifics of the API would've changed from 2012, so I would try to look at the API-documentation and see how to implement a solution. If you have problems with _that_ specific problem, then that is considered on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Excel unfortunately does not keep edit histories so there is no way to access it.

You would have to write your own script to inspect or listen for changes and keep those changes on another sheet, for example, or you could create another column which automatically fills the user name and date when the row is changed.

Something like what is described in this [post](https://thkbrain.wordpress.com/2018/07/28/excel-vba-create-a-history-sheet-on-your-workbook/). Which among other things, demonstrates how to get the current time and current user.

Or, if there is the option to move to Google Sheets, they recently implemented some cell history functionality which is pretty awesome!